# Export file generated empty with ora2pg type COPY while migrating from oracle to postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle, ora2pg

I'm trying to migrate from a Oracle DB to PostgreSQL using Ora2pg tool in Linux environment(Redhat).
The issue I'm facing is that the output file generated is blank, there is no content in it.
There are no error displayed in the process as well.
Weird thing is, the exact same configuration file work fine on windows environment, but I want to use the Linux environment as it is faster and supports parallel process. Following is the command I run

```
ora2pg -b /home/ora2pg-24.1/exports_folder/copy_export -d --plsql -c /home/ora2pg-24.1/conf_files/ora2pg_copy.conf
```

Following is the output for the command due to the -d flag

https://pastebin.com/T0j64AgA

The configuration file
https://pastebin.com/2NH5NDkr

Previously when I had mentioned multiple tables(more than 10) instead of a single one in the configuration file, a few files got generated, but even they were not correctly generated or only a few were populated and others were empty.

Please let me know what I might be doing wrong in this case.